# SQL Server WHERE IS NULL OR IN MULTIPLE ROWS (VALUES)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
--Main Query
SELECT * FROM tblUser u
WHERE
--Search Criteria 1
-- Sub Query 
((SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle 
like 'MaritalStatus')
IS NULL
OR 
u.MaritalStatus IN 
-- Sub Query 
(SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle 
like 'MaritalStatus'))

AND
--Search Criteria 2
-- Sub Query 
((SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle 
like 'CountryOfResidence')
IS NULL
OR 
u.CountryOfResidence IN 
-- Sub Query 
(SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle 
like 'CountryOfResidence'))
```

-- When sub-query

```
 (SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se WHERE 
 se.SearchEntityTitle like 'MaritalStatus')
```

returns:

NULL [main query] works fine

1 ROW [main query] works fine

2 or more ROWS [main query] DOES NOT work.

IS NULL can't accpet multiple values so what should I do?

Comment: Question is not clear.  The SQL statement is hard to read.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Help us help you.  Describe what you are trying to do.  Post table structure, sample input, expected output.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "DOES NOT work" is not a problem description. Do you get an exception? no rows are returned? incorrect data is returned? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE you condition on this

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se 
    WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle like 'MaritalStatus'
    AND se.SearchEntityId = sp.SearchEntityId)
    AND s.UserId = @UserId))
```

Comment: sometimes sub-query returns NULL how can I use EXISTS with NULL

Comment: if somtimes sub-query returns null it's mean that main query return nothing, with exists main query return nothing too

Answer (score 0):

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT se.SearchEntityId FROM tblSearchEntity se 
    WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle like 'MaritalStatus'
    AND se.SearchEntityId = sp.SearchEntityId)
    AND s.UserId = @UserId))
```

Instead of doing the above, it would be better to use JOINS's. For example, the above would have the following joins

LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblSearchEntity] se ON se.searchentityId = sp.searchentityId

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you tried to do, I think with the help of a couple of CTEs and a few changes in the main query you will get what you want.

Here is what I came up with. Bare in mind that I can't test it since you have not provided sample data or desired results.

```
;WITH MaritalStatusCte AS
(
    SELECT SearchEntityId 
    FROM tblSearchEntity 
    WHERE SearchEntityTitle = 'MaritalStatus'  
), CountryOfResidenceCte AS
(
    SELECT SearchEntityId 
    FROM tblSearchEntity 
    WHERE se.SearchEntityTitle = 'CountryOfResidence'  
)


SELECT * 
FROM tblUser as u
WHERE 
(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MaritalStatusCte) = 0)
    OR EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MaritalStatusCte 
        WHERE SearchEntityId = uMaritalStatus
    )
)
AND 
(
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CountryOfResidenceCte) = 0)
    OR EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CountryOfResidenceCte 
        WHERE SearchEntityId = CountryOfResidence
    )
)
```